# Where are we shown Rose's surname?

Tags: fullmetal-alchemist-series

According to the [Fullmetal Alchemist Wiki](http://fma.wikia.com/wiki/Ros%C3%A9_Thomas), Rose, the character who appears in the Lior arcs of FMA, has "Thomas" for a surname. While [the Wikipedia entry on her](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Fullmetal_Alchemist_characters#Ros.C3.A9) simply refers to her as Rose, a quick Google search for `fma rose` yields several results for her as "Rose Thomas".

However, I don't recall Rose ever being referred to as anything other than "Rose" during the course of either Fullmetal Alchemist anime series or in the manga. (It is of course possible that I don't remember the 2003 anime very well, since I binge-watched it a year ago and might have missed some details.) What's the origin of her supposed surname, and is this even something "official" in any capacity?

Comment: IIRC this appears in the ["Fullmetal Alchemist Anime Profiles" book](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Fullmetal-Alchemist-Profiles-Manga/dp/1421507684). I don't have a copy (yet), though, so I can't confirm.

Comment: I did some searching and I do believe her name is "Roze Thomas"

Comment: I am sure this doesn't appear in either the manga or anime from what I remember.

Comment: @Jonco98: in the official subs for both series her name appears as Rose. The "Thomas" bit doesn't seem to ever be mentioned.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Rosé's surname is mentioned in the 2004 FMA game Fullmetal Alchemist: Stray Rondo released by Bandai.**

This is clear from [*this video*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gOvJrACETd4) where the aforementioned game is played on an emulator.

If you go to 2:49 you can see Rosé introducing herself to the Elric brothers as: Roze Tōmasu (in Japanese writing, katakana is used for writing non-Japanese names, ロゼ・トーマス) which is then adapted to English as Rosé (not like the flower rose) Thomas.

This surname appears neither in the manga nor in the anime. It is common however for wikis to adopt such information from officially released games.

Here is the aforementioned screenshot: [image]

Comment: Very good answer! +1. Nice catch